# Extending python with a OpenCV C++ module

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I have been trying to extend python with a OpenCV module written in C++.
I am encountering 2 problems during this.

1) Setup.py - How does one include cv.h library here?

```
libraries = ['opencv'],
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib'],
```

2) Importing the cv.h in the C++ module file?

```
#include "cv.h"
using namespace cv;
```

Throws compile time error -
`t1.cpp:3:16: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work

1) In Setup.py

```
include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'],
libraries = ['opencv_core', 'opencv_highgui'],
library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib'],
```

2) C++ module

`#include <opencv/cv.h>`

#include <opencv/highgui.h>

Answer (score 1):

The C++ header file is `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, if you have `/usr/local/include` on your header path. So what you should be doing is -

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
```

As for including the OpenCV libarries for linking, you should look at the libraries in `/usr/local/lib/libopencv*`. There are several OpenCV libraries, each corresponding to one package, so you may not need to link all the libraries, if you are not using that package.

Personally, I would work by statically linking your module with a `libopencv.a` and the linking the entire module to Python. If you are bothered about extra code being linked, you can strip the unused symbols.

Comment: Thanks subzero, but I already got it to work. had an issue with the highgui.h as well. Thanks again.